# Windows 8.1: Can't ctrl+tab under most circumstances

Tags: windows-8.1

This started happening about a week ago. I think it might've been around the time I got ShadowPlay working, but I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

The really weird thing is that I can ctrl+shift+tab just fine. It's just ctrl+tab that doesn't work.

Even more strangely, I **can** ctrl+tab when I'm using the Steam overlay in a game. However, it doesn't work anywhere else. Steam chat outside of the overlay, Chrome, Internet Explorer, anywhere.

Alt-tabbing is unaffected, by the way.